# Wordpress If Parent { } else if child { }

Tags: php, wordpress, parent, categories

I would say I am a noob at php, but I feel I atleast undertands it a little bit.

Okay, so I am making a theme in wordpress and I have a problem with category.php. When wordpress reads in category.php i want a if statment that looks something like this.

```
<?php
$cate = get_category($cat);

if ($cate->category_parent == 1) { 
     require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/category-parent.php' ); } 
else if($cate->category_parent == 0) { 
     require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/category-child.php' ) } 
endif; ?>
```

Yeah so if Parent use this template, and if child use this template, by template I mean like page.php templates.

Thanks!

Comment: `. '/category-parent.php ); }` => `. '/category-parent.php' ); }`. The same with "child"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sep = '»';
$parents = get_category_parents( $cat, TRUE, $sep );
$parents = explode( $sep, trim( $parents, $sep ) );
if( 1 === count( $parents ) ) {
    /* No category parents. */
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/category-parent.php' );
}
else {
    /* One or more parent categories. */
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/category-child.php' );
}
```